# rlink to a remote installation

Tags: rlink

I have a r installation on a server machine and have mathematica on my laptop. I have been using `DatabaseLink` to connect to the remote sql server and performing queries. I would now like to use mathematica on my machine to connect with r installation on the remote machine to pass codes from here and get results from the remote r installation. This is necessary as i don't have a lot of RAM on my machine. I know about `RLink` but can't find instruction to connect to a remote installation.

Somebody please help.

Comment: Installing R using the Shared link suggested by Edmund works fine except it is not running R on the server but on the local machine. Is there a way to connect to R running on the server thereby using the resources of the server rather than the local machine.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use [`InstallR`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/ref/InstallR.html) with the `"RHomeLocation"` option if you are on a Windows OS.

```
Needs["RLink`"]
InstallR["RHomeLocation"->"\\\\servername\\sharename\\path to R_HOME of R Distrtribution"]
```

`"RHomeLocation"` works for local installations of R but I have not tried it for remote installations of R.  There are a few more `InstallR` options that you should consider as well.  Also have a read of the [*RLink* User Guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/tutorial/UsingRLink.html) as you may have to run [`RLinkResourcesInstall`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/ref/RLinkResourcesInstall.html). It also gives information on how to optimise calls and data transfer between R and *Mathematica*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: if you can guide me how to point to the remote server. In my remote desktop application i am able to access it with computer name `tm46:10346` and the location of r installation on that system is `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.4revised`. How path exactly should i use? I tried before to import a file but the path never worked.

Comment: @user13892 You need to setup the folder as a shared folder on your network which will allow you to choose the name. Perhaps you should share the *R* directory so you can connect to different revisions. If you call the share RRevisions, then the command would be `InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "\\\\tm46:10346\\RRevisions\\R-3.2.4revised"]`

Comment: It is able to locate the folder now but still i am getting this error, InstallR::fail: Failed to install R. The following error was encountered: Unable to load dynamic libraries

Comment: Ok it is working fine now. But it is using the RAM of my local system in which i have mathematica rather than the server where the r resides.